# Is this scroll effect custom or is this a well known special effect?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas, frontend

I stumbled across [this website](http://bericotechnologies.com/) and while it is too cluttered for my tastes, I love the depth effect that you see as you scroll. There appears to be a layer that is masked and scrolls at a much slower speed than the main layer. I was just curious if this special effect is something canned that can be slapped into a website or not. It would be interesting to try and reproduce it from scratch. I have a hard time distilling where in the code this effect is being carried out when I view the page source.

Comment: you mean parallax scrolling?

Comment: yes, I should have said that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/

boom, thanks Froient for bringing up the word parallax, I googled that and found what I needed! This is going to be amazing for my art portfolio!

Answer (score 1):

Its not a 'depth effect' There are multiple script at play here...
1) paralax scrolling (background images fixed behind the main page)
2) muliple jquery effects to bring content in from the side or fade in etc - triggered as you scroll